# If checkbox checked, save NSString to database

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a checkbox in my app. If the box is checked, I want to set the word "medium" to save to my database field. In my "if checked1 = YES" block, I've created an NSString and set it to "Medium". That said, in my submit button block, what sort of code should I use to save the set string?

The structure of the JSON being returned from my database requires the below code in order for me to input the string, but I'm not sure how to rewrite it to accommodate NSString (I used this previously for NSArray)?

```
NSDictionary *bodyValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:medium, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
NSDictionary *languageDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:bodyValues] forKey:@"und"];

[nodeData setObject:languageDict forKey:@"size"];
```

The error I get when running this block is:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of
>   keys (1)'

See Code below - hope I explained this clearly, and thanks:

**.h**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSString *medium;
```

**.m**

```
- (IBAction)checkButton:(id)sender {
    if (!checked1) {
        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = YES;

        NSString *medium = @"Medium";

        NSLog(@"button 1");
    }

    else if (checked1) {
        [checkboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)submitPet:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [nodeData setValue: self.dogsName.text forKey:@"title"];
    [nodeData setObject:@"pets" forKey:@"type"];

    NSDictionary *bodyValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:medium, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *languageDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:bodyValues] forKey:@"und"];
    [nodeData setObject:languageDict forKey:@"size"];

    [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Node saved!");
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are passing `nil` for one of your `dictionaryWithObjects` calls. You can't add `nil` to a Dictionary. Use `nslog` to print out your variables before they're added.

Comment: For some reason, I keep getting a warning saying NSString 'medium' is an unused variable (even though I'm using it)? I assume it's using the property stated in my .h file but not the NSString set in my if checked statement?

Comment: You should be setting `self.medium = @"Medium";`, not creating a new string, that's not doing anything. And then say `arrayWithObjects:self.medium, nil`

Comment: No error, I get "node saved successfully" via my NSLog. However the value doesnt seem to post to my database. I check the backlog, and it sees that "Medium" is being passed to the "size" field - but it doesn't seem to want to save. The other value I'm saving in the code above (forKey: title) works just fine. Note: I also tried  [nodeData setObject:self.medium forKey:@"size"]; and again, it appears to pass the data, but the save doesn't occur.

Comment: We're starting to get into asking a new question territory here, but I'd print out `nodeData` after setting everything but before saving to see what's actually being saved.

Comment: Printed nodeData, and data is being saved (shocking). Print out is: This is the nodeData {
    Size =     {
        und =         (
                        {
                value = Medium;
            }
        );
    };